# Using hashlib on a matplotlib object

Tags: python, matplotlib, hash, cryptography, hashlib

Using Python, I am trying to write tests that compare the current output with an expected output. The output is a matplotlib figure and I would like to do this without saving the figure to a file.

I had the idea to find the cryptographic hash of the object so that I would just need to compare one hash with another to confirm that the entire object is unchanged from what is expected.

This works fine for a numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import hashlib
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.rand(10,100)
actual_hash = hashlib.sha1(A).hexdigest()
expected_hash = '38f682cab1f0bfefb84cdd6b112b7d10cde6147f'
assert actual_hash == expected_hash
```

When I try this on a matplotlib object I get: `TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required`

```
import hashlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
Y = np.sin(0.5*X)
plt.plot(X,Y)
fig = plt.gcf()
actual_hash = hashlib.sha1(fig).hexdigest() #this raises the TypeError
```

Any ideas how I can use hashlib to find the cryptographic hash of a matplotlib object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the figure as a numpy array using [`buffer_rgba()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/backend_agg_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg.buffer_rgba). Before using it you must actually draw the figure:

> draw must be called at least once before this function will work and
> to update the renderer for any subsequent changes to the Figure.

```
import hashlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
Y = np.sin(0.5*X)
plt.plot(X,Y)
canvas = plt.gcf().canvas
canvas.draw()

actual_hash = hashlib.sha1(np.array(canvas.buffer_rgba())).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.